# Wordpress plugin settings page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, google-analytics

I'm writing my first WP plugin, so I'm starting simple. I thought I'd create a simple plugin that would inject a Google Analytics snippet into the page head. Everything seems to work, except that the plugin settings page is blank. There should be a simple form where I can input the Analytics UA, but the page is completely blank. I've looked the code over and over and I'm not seeing the problem.

```html
<?php 
    /*
    Plugin Name: Analytics
    Plugin URI: https://chriscather.wordpress.com
    Description: Plugin for adding Google Analytics to website
    Author: C. Cather
    Version: 1.0
    Author URI: https://chriscather.wordpress.com
    */

add_action('admin_menu', 'cc_analytics_menu');

function cc_analytics_menu() {
    add_menu_page('CC Analytics', 'CC Analytics', 'administrator', 'cc_analytics_settings_page', 'cc_analytics_menu', plugins_url('analytics/images/analytics.png'));
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'cc_analytics_settings' );

function cc_analytics_settings() {
    register_setting( 'cc_analytics_settings_group', 'accountant_name' );
}

function cc_analytics_settings_page(){?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Staff Details</h2>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php settings_fields( 'cc_analytics_settings_group' ); ?>
            <?php do_settings_sections( 'cc_analytics_settings_group' ); ?>
            <table class="form-table">
                <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row">Accountant Name</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="accountant_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('accountant_name') ); ?>" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <?php submit_button(); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php }

add_action( 'wp_head', 'cc_analytics' );
    function cc_analytics() { ?>
        <script>
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            ga('create', "<?php cc_analytics_settings_group('accountant_name') ?>", 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');

        </script>
    <?php }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by instead of using a PHP variable to call in the Google Analytics code, calling the function from the form in the Settings page.

```
ga('create', '<?php echo get_option('accountant_name', ''); ?>', 'auto');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rename `cc_analytics_menu` argument in `add_menu_page`.

**Your Code:**

```
 add_menu_page('CC Analytics', 'CC Analytics', 'administrator', 'cc_analytics_settings_page', 'cc_analytics_menu', plugins_url('analytics/images/analytics.png'));
```

**Modify Code:**

Renamed `cc_analytics_menu` to `cc_analytics_menu_function`.

**Also rename callback function:**

```
add_menu_page('CC Analytics', 'CC Analytics', 'administrator', 'cc_analytics_settings_page', 'cc_analytics_menu_function', plugins_url('analytics/images/analytics.png'));

function cc_analytics_menu_function(){?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Staff Details</h2>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php settings_fields( 'cc_analytics_settings_group' ); ?>
            <?php do_settings_sections( 'cc_analytics_settings_group' ); ?>
            <table class="form-table">
                <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row">Accountant Name</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="accountant_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('accountant_name') ); ?>" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <?php submit_button(); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php }
```

**Full Plugin Code:**

```
<?php 
    /*
    Plugin Name: Analytics
    Plugin URI: https://chriscather.wordpress.com
    Description: Plugin for adding Google Analytics to website
    Author: C. Cather
    Version: 1.0
    Author URI: https://chriscather.wordpress.com
    */

add_action('admin_menu', 'cc_analytics_menu');

function cc_analytics_menu() {
    add_menu_page('CC Analytics', 'CC Analytics', 'administrator', 'cc_analytics_settings_page', 'cc_analytics_menu_function', plugins_url('analytics/images/analytics.png'));
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'cc_analytics_settings' );

function cc_analytics_settings() {
    register_setting( 'cc_analytics_settings_group', 'accountant_name' );
}

function cc_analytics_menu_function(){?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Staff Details</h2>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php settings_fields( 'cc_analytics_settings_group' ); ?>
            <?php do_settings_sections( 'cc_analytics_settings_group' ); ?>
            <table class="form-table">
                <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row">Accountant Name</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="accountant_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('accountant_name') ); ?>" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <?php submit_button(); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php }

add_action( 'wp_head', 'cc_analytics' );
    function cc_analytics() { ?>
        <script>
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            ga('create', "<?php cc_analytics_settings_group('accountant_name') ?>", 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');

        </script>
    <?php }
```

Comment: The form now appears in the backend, hooray! However, I just realized that my using a PHP call inside of javascript is causing the page to break. Lame. I came up with this call, but I'm not sure how to create the variable: `'" . $trackerCode . "'` I tried something simple like `$trackerCode = cc_analytics_menu_function(accountant_name);` but that broke the page.